# Unity3d: Angle between two points not consistent

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, virtual-reality, angle

So, I have two game objects `P1` and `P2`, these two game objects are associated with the trackers on my left leg and right leg respectively.

So, I need to find the angle between them.

[image]

So, this is how my `P1` and `P2` would look if I face forward and take my right leg front.

```
private double calculateAngle(double P1X, double P1Y, double P2X, double P2Y,
        double P3X, double P3Y)
{

    double numerator = P2Y * (P1X - P3X) + P1Y * (P3X - P2X) + P3Y * (P2X - P1X);
    double denominator = (P2X - P1X) * (P1X - P3X) + (P2Y - P1Y) * (P1Y - P3Y);
    double ratio = numerator / denominator;

    double angleRad = Math.Atan(ratio);
    double angleDeg = (angleRad * 180) / Math.PI;

    if (angleDeg < 0)
    {
        angleDeg = 180 + angleDeg;
    }

    return angleDeg;
}

    calculateAngle(LeftLegController.position.x, LeftLegController.position.z,
              RightLegController.position.x, RightLegController.position.z, 
        LeftLegController.position.x, RightLegController.position.z))
```

It should always be a right angle triangle due to this.

So, this is the code I'm using to calculate the angle between my `P1` and `P2`,

When I face front, the angle between my two game objects is different and when I face left and move my right leg front (Which would look like this)

[image]

My `Angle 1` and `Angle 2` are coming entirely different. So, what is a better way to find an angle (Ignoring the y axis, its as if the points are projected on the ground)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the method you're looking for is [`Vector3.SignedAngle()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html).

```cs
var A = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(P3.position - P1.position, Vector3.up);
var B = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(P2.position - P1.position, Vector3.up);
print(Vector3.SignedAngle(A, B, Vector3.up));
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the dot product of two vectors A and B is |A| |B| cos theta. So take your dot product, divide by the magnitudes of each vector, and take the arccos to get your angle. (In fact you probably want the cos anyway!)